# How to take multiple functions as variable arguments in Scala ?

Tags: scala, syntax, functional-programming

In order to take multiple variables as arguments for data types in Scala we can write something as :

```
def test(args: String*)
```

How can we take multiple functions as arguments in the same spirit? (The Syntax?) I could not find anything after much googling.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Functions in Scala are values with types like any other values, and `A => B` (or, equivalently, `Function1[A, B]`) is the type of a function from `A` to `B`. So if for example you want to take a variable number of functions from strings to strings, you could write the following:

```
def test(funcs: (String => String)*) = ???
```

You could actually skip the internal parentheses and write `funcs: String => String*`, but I personally find the precedence there a bit unclear.

Comment: For completeness: `def test(args: Function1[String, String]*)`

Comment: Always keep in mind the option to declare a type alias. In this case, e.g., `type Str2Str = String => String` then `def test(funcs: Str2Str*)`.